# microsoft edge new tab window resizing

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm programming a responsive website and I like the resizing from the Microsoft Edge browser when it's on the "new tab" page. Like, first, the white bars left and right go away, but when the news blocks can't be on the page anymore, they go from 3 news blocks next to each other to 2 news blocks. 
 The second part I already have, I'm doing it with media queries (@media screen only and (min-width: 768px) { *code goes here* }
But the first part.... I want to add that to my site!

### **EDIT**

The answer is the following: for the body, set a `max-width: ;` to whatever you like. If it still doesn't work, set a `margin: 0 auto;` on the body as well.

Answer (score 0):

You set the width of the parent element of e.g. the blocks and margin to:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: More specific please. What HTML tag?